# How to use the last entry of datetime in between sql query?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, xampp

I have an arduino device that sends sms to my usb broadband stick that saves the data sent by the sms. The problem is that there will be 2 duino devices that will send data to the usb broadband stick, I need to average the data given by the 2 devices.I have a table named humidity and fields named id, degree and setTime which is in `Timestamp(3)` format.  Here's what I have right now `SELECT AVG(setPercent) as humidav
FROM humidity
WHERE setTime BETWEEN "LAST ENTRY FOR TIMESTAMP` and `LAST ENTRY FOR TIMESTAMP +1 second` how do i get the last entry for `setTime` so I can use it in my sql query and add `1` second to it so I can average the `degree`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Max` function to get the largest date:

```
WHERE setTime between MAX(setTime) and 
DATE_ADD(max(seTime), INTERVAL 1 second)
```